# Entity Framework vs ADO.Net with TVP Updating Multiple Rows

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ado.net

I decided to convert my ADO.Net with Table Value Parameter code for updating multiple rows of 10,000 rows to Entity Framework as in the code below. The results below shows that it took ADO.Net TVP less than 1 second while Entity Framework took 2 minutes : 34 seconds. My question now is how do I speedup my Entity Framework code to run as fast as my ADO.Net with TVP code?

[image]

```
[Table("Employee")]
public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public string Town { get; set; }
    public string PostCode { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();


        Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 10000; i++)
        {

            Employee emp = new Employee();

            emp.EmployeeId = i;
            emp.FirstName = "FirstName" + i;
            emp.Lastname = "Lastname" + i;
            emp.Town = "Town" + i;
            emp.PostCode = "PostCode" + i;

            employees.Add(emp);

        }

        var e = employees.OrderBy(o => Convert.ToInt32(o.EmployeeId)).ToList();
        SaveEmployeeToDatabase(e, "EmployeeDB");
        stopwatch.Stop();
        string t = stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine("Time Elapse: " + t + ": " + "ADO.Net Update Multiple Rows with TVP");


        /*Entity Entity Framework Update Multiple Rows*/

        EmployeeContext db = new EmployeeContext();

        Stopwatch stopwatch1 = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 10000; i++)
        {

            Employee emp1 = new Employee();

            emp1.EmployeeId = i;
            emp1.FirstName = "NewFirstName" + i;
            emp1.Lastname = "NewLastname" + i;
            emp1.Town = "NewTown" + i;
            emp1.PostCode = "NewPostCode" + i;

            db.Employees.Add(emp1);
            db.Entry(emp1).State = EntityState.Modified;

        }

        db.SaveChanges();
        stopwatch1.Stop();
        string t1 = stopwatch1.Elapsed.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine("Time Elapse: " + t1 + ": " + "Entity Framework Update Multiple Rows");
        Console.Read();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > My question now is how do I speedup my Entity Framework code to run as fast as my ADO.Net with TVP code?

You don't.  You "drop down" to ADO.NET or TSQL for bulk operations and complicated queries.

But still save a ton of time and effort by using EF for most of your queries and transactions.

Comment: Thanks David for your answer.